# How to migrate or import files from one Xcode Project to another?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3

I created a Mac OS project using Xcode 8 and cannot export the archive file.  The documentation suggests that a top level app is needed which I must have omitted in haste.

I created a second project and tested the export feature from archive.  It works as intended.

How do I migrate the storyboard, swift files and all relevant assets from the problem project to the one that works as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most sensible way is likely:

> `Xcode` > `File` > `Add Files` to (New Project)... or shortcut <kbd>⌥</kbd>
>   <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

You could also drag and drop from the old project to the new one, although it seems to work better sometimes to use the `Add Files` option from the `File` menu.